# How to convert from per-hour to per-month units, respecting the variation in length of individual months?

Tags: google-earth-engine

The [GPM: Monthly Global Precipitation Measurement (GPM) v6](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NASA_GPM_L3_IMERG_MONTHLY_V06) dataset consists of monthly images that have precipitation band with data in units of **mm/hr**. How can the precipitation data be converted into units of **mm/month**, respecting the variation in the length of individual months?

Answer (score 3):

Start with an image collection of monthly precipitation data:

```
// Copyright 2020 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
var ic = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/GPM_L3/IMERG_MONTHLY_V06")
           .filterDate('2019', '2021')
           .select('precipitation');
```

Write a function that takes a monthly image, determines the number of hours in that month, calculates the precipitation in that month, and adds that information as a new band of the image:

```
var addMonthlyPrecip = function (img) {
  var start = ee.Date(img.get('system:time_start'));
  var end = start.advance(1, 'month');
  var hoursInMonth = end.difference(start, 'hours');
  return img.addBands(img.multiply(hoursInMonth).rename('precip_mm_month'));
};
```

Next apply that function to every image in the collection.

```
ic = ic.map(addMonthlyPrecip);
```

The new data can now be displayed or analyzed further:

```
Map.addLayer(ic, {bands:'precip_mm_month', max: 720});
```

The results look rather ghostly...

[image: Screenshot of the monthly precipitation]

The complete script is available here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/49de1393b88184d7d6a247dc2e1357bb